# Is there an API for running Scala REPL programmatically?

Tags: api, scala, read-eval-print-loop

Based on [a thread](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Compiler-API-td1992165.html) and the [Scala interpreter sources](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src//compiler/scala/tools/nsc/interpreter/ILoop.scala) it looks like it would not be that hard to get the equivalent of

```
def runLine(line: String): String
```

but has someone written this already?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launch Scala REPL programatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456868/launch-scala-repl-programatically)

Comment: This answer gives more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160355/drop-into-interpreter-during-arbitrary-scala-code-location . Note that the library has interface has changed (refactored) as of Scala 2.9. Also, you might run into problems with the classpath of the embedded REPL not being the same as the parent process; some solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121567/embedded-scala-repl-inherits-parent-classpath

Comment: @Daniel that's attempting to do a quite different thing, which is interrupt a scala program to start the usual REPL. I'm trying to duplicate the behavior of the REPL in a non-REPL.

Comment: @Owen [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905948/how-do-i-embed-the-scala-2-8-interpreter-in-a-java-application), then?

Comment: @Daniel That's pretty close, though it uses `interpreter.main(settings)`, so it's still using the standard REPL's main loop.

Comment: @Owen Well, there's [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348825/scala-tools-nsc-interpreter-how-to-execute-interpreter-statements-so-that-the), though it specifies 2.7.7. Not sure if it still works. It's also not a duplicate of the question -- the guy already had it figured out. [This other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752206/dynamically-create-class-in-scala-should-i-use-interpreter) actually compiles and loads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many examples floating out there, but they may be hard to find. Here is the one I wrote a while back:

http://code.google.com/p/simplex3d/source/browse/trunk/Simplex3dConsole/src/simplex3d/console/SimpleInterpreter.scala?r=790

The tricky part is to get the interpreter to load Scala jars. I have loaded jars manually to make it work with web-start, but in your case, simple `settings.usejavacp.value = true` may suffice.

You can see the interpreter in action here: http://www.simplex3d.org/console/